# Сортировка Map в обратном порядке по значению

Tags: java

Помогите, нужно отсортировать Map в обратном порядке по значению (Value).

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Text1", 0);
map.put("Text2", 1);
map.put("Text3", 2);
map.put("Text4", 0);
```

Надо чтобы оно отсортировало так:

```
Key - Value:

Text3 - 2
Text2 - 1
Text1 - 0
Text4 - 0
```

или

```
Text3 - 2
Text2 - 1
Text4 - 0
Text1 - 0
```

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

Может кому будет полезным, вот как я сделал:

```
private static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Collections.reverseOrder()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (e1, e2) -> e1,
                    LinkedHashMap::new
            ));
}
```